# Next quarter without using Quarter function

Tags: mysql

I have a query which runs on particular dates. Whenever the query runs, it has to pick up the next quarter dates.

- 1st quarter Jan-March
- 2nd quarter April-June
- 3rd quarter July-September
- 4th quarter October- December

Suppose  my query runs in April. I need to pick the data from July 1st to September 30th, without using the MySQL `QUARTER` function.

Comment: Why the restriction? What's wrong with using QUARTER()?

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(NOW()), MONTH(NOW()), '01') + INTERVAL
       3 * QUARTER(NOW()) + 1 - MONTH(NOW())
       MONTH;
--> 2016-07-01
```

If you don't need the date of the beginning of the next quarter, but need the string '3rd quarter July-September', then use a `CASE` clause.

Without `QUARTER`:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(NOW()), MONTH(NOW()), '01') + INTERVAL
       3 * FLOOR(MONTH(NOW())/3+1) + 1 - MONTH(NOW())
       MONTH;
```

Because `QUARTER(x)` is the same as `FLOOR(MONTH(x)/3+1)`.

Comment: But this actually uses the `QUARTER` function?

Comment: Why no quarter?  Added code.

Comment: I don't mind using `QUARTER`, but the OP wanted *Next quarter without using Quarter function*, maybe he likes reinventing the wheel :)

Comment: And he wants us to do the inventing for him?

Answer (score 0):

**NEXT QUARTER DATE IS:**

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(NOW()), (QUARTER(NOW()) * 3) - 2 , '01') + INTERVAL 3 MONTH;
```

**PREVIOUS QUARTER DATE IS:**

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(NOW()), (QUARTER(NOW()) * 3) - 2 , '01') - INTERVAL 3 MONTH;
```